# python - Why do I have duplicate keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.7

The key is a string and the value of the dictionary allLines is a list of python objects.

```
original_list = allLines.get(key)
new_list = []
if original_list is not None:
    for l in original_list:
      new_list.append(l)  #add rest
new_list.append(temp) # plus new one
allLines[key] = new_list
```

temps is new object added to end of the list.

When I execute the last line it should be replacing the original_list entirely but when I print the dict I am getting duplicate keys with different list for each time a run the operation. What would be the right way to do this?

1st time I run this

```
allLines = {"boolean mark":[obj1]}
```

2nd time I run this I get:

```
allLines = {"boolean mark":[obj1], "boolean mark":[obj1, temp]}
```

Instead of:

```
allLines = {"boolean mark":[obj1, temp]}
```

Comment: It's not very clear without examples.

Comment: what `temp` is? What `key` is?

Comment: Why not just use `copy.copy()` or `copy.deepcopy()`?  And for that matter, why copy at all if you are just going to overwrite the original anyway?

Comment: Why not just append to `original_list` instead? Use `allLines.setdefault(key, []).append(temp)`, no loops needed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Looks like he'd still need to check for existence of `key` and set a default initial list if `key` is not present, but yeah.

Comment: @sr2222: that is what `.setdefault()` *does*. That one line can replace *all of the code* the OP posted.

Comment: As the output posted is impossible, it's clear you didn't show the actual code and you are doing something wrong instead.

Comment: No, Python dictionaries *never* do that. You *cannot* get a duplicate key like that. I think you must be getting confused between subtly differing keys somewhere instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oops, didn't notice that part of your response, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

```
DATA = {"records": [{"key1": "AAA", "key2": "BBB", "key3": "CCC", "key4": "AAA"}]}

for name, datalist in DATA.iteritems():  # Or items() in Python 3.x
    for datadict in datalist:
        for key, value in datadict.items():
            if value == "AAA":
                datadict[key] = "XXX"

print (DATA)
```

output:

```
{'records': [{'key3': 'CCC', 'key2': 'BBB', 'key1': 'XXX', 'key4': 'XXX'}]}
```

taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1076577/205426)

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your results with the code below. I had to add a few things to make what you posted executable, but afterwards, it seems do what you want, not what you say is happening -- which is impossible anyway, because a dictionary can't have duplicate keys as you claim is happening. The two keys *must* differ in some way, and if you can figure out what the difference is, you may be able to solve your problem yourself.

```
def obj(name):
    return type(name, (object,), dict(__repr__=lambda self: name))()

allLines = {}  # global var

def operation(key, temp):
    original_list = allLines.get(key)
    new_list = []
    if original_list is not None:
        for l in original_list:
            new_list.append(l)  #add rest
    new_list.append(temp) # plus new one
    allLines[key] = new_list

operation('boolean mark', obj('obj1'))
print 'allLines =', allLines
operation('boolean mark', obj('temp'))
print 'allLines =', allLines
```

Output:

```
allLines = {'boolean mark': [obj1]}
allLines = {'boolean mark': [obj1, temp]}
```