# How to replace the subject (fixed position) in a string

Tags: python, string, replace

Target to modify:

```
Sample ="FST~C~D~170101 FST~C~D~170102 FST~C~D~170103 FST~C~D~170104"
```

I want to replace "170101","170102","170103","170104" with "170413",
"170414","170415","170416"(the current date and days behind)
The output should be:

```
"FST~C~D~170413 FST~C~D~170414 FST~C~D~0415 FST~C~D~170416"
```

I tried with `replace()` but failed. I know it is due a "string" is not allowed to be modified. Anyone can help on this!

Comment: How exactly did you try to replace those…?

Comment: Post your code please

Answer (score 0):

Because of the nature of your data there, you could probably benefit from slicing your data into variables and adding them to a list or dictionary. From there you can use a for loop to operate on specific values.

This should help with slicing: [Is there a way to substring a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/is-there-a-way-to-substring-a-string-in-python?rq=1)

```
>>> x = "FST~C~D~170101 FST~C~D~170102 FST~C~D~170103 FST~C~D~170104"
>>> a = x[:7]
>>> print(a)
'FST~C~D~'
>>> b = x[8:13]
>>> print(b)
170101
```

... continue this with the rest of your data

```
>>> mydict = {a:b,c:d,e:f,g:h}
```

Then with a dictionary of your values, operate on them. To do that here's a helpful answer: [Replacing values in a Python list/dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076536/replacing-values-in-a-python-list-dictionary)

I do hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex to find the old dates and define a function to calculate the new ones:

```
import re
from datetime import date, datetime

sample = "FST~C~D~170101 FST~C~D~170102 FST~C~D~170103 FST~C~D~170104"

def parse_yymmdd(yymmdd):
    return datetime.strptime(yymmdd, '%y%m%d').date()

first_date = parse_yymmdd('170101')

def replace_date(old_date):
    old_date = parse_yymmdd(old_date.group(0))
    new_date = date.today() + (old_date - first_date)
    return new_date.strftime('%y%m%d')

print(re.sub(r'(?<=FST~C~D~)\d+\b', replace_date, sample))
# "FST~C~D~170413 FST~C~D~170414 FST~C~D~170415 FST~C~D~170416"
```